# using AND on count functions returns incorrect values

Tags: python, pandas

i am attempting to return the values from a csv files using python,

to fetch the amounts for each field i have used the .count function which has worked with 1 value,
i.e. attempting to count the amount of Males in a list, however when i attempt to pass 2 conditions through this function using a & statement the numbers returned are false

for instance, i know that there are 489 males in the CSV file through

```
true_male_count = x.count('Male')
```

however when i want to find the Males whom's loan value is 'Y' as shown below

```
true_male_count = x.count('Male') & y.count('Y')
```

i find that there is 416 males with who also have a loan value of Y, i cant be sure if this is false, but if i change the value from 'Y' to 'N' it tells me that there are 192 Males with a loan value of n which is impossible.
i have attempted to use loops to return these values rather than the count function but to no avail

i need these variables to return the correct values, full code below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
  
df = pd.read_csv('csvfile.csv')

Gender = df['Gender']
Loan = df['Loan_Status']

GenderCondition = (df['Gender'] == 'Male' , df['Loan_Status'] == 'Y')
LoanCondition = (df['Loan_Status'] == 'Y')

x=list(Gender)
y=list(Loan)

true_male_count = x.count('Male') & y.count('N')
true_female_count = x.count('Female') & y.count('N')

true_loan_count = y.count('Y')
false_loan_count = y.count('N')
    

print(true_male_count)
```

Comment: `list.count` returns an `int`.  If you `&` two `ints` you're doing a bitwise AND between the two numbers, not a set intersection between the two columns that the lists and their counts were originally generated from.

Comment: Shouldn't `GenderCondition` just be `(df['Gender'] == 'Male')`, not a tuple of `df['Gender'] == 'Male'` and `df['Loan_Status'] == 'Y'`?

Comment: You're trying to find males that have a loan=Y. You need to apply that condition first, then count

Comment: On the other hand the full code shows that you're trying to find the totals by gender and loan. You're using all combinations of Gender and Loan_Status. Try `df.groupby(by=["Gender","Loan_Status"]).count()`

Comment: i have been able to group the properties through this function, now i am just attempting to fetch the individual values for each option through this function

Comment: do you have any advice on this?